# Greendao: How to update to-many entities

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, sql-update, greendao

My app uses a database with `SongVersions` having many `Tracks`. This to-manx relationship is generated by greendao and works fine so far.

But now I try to update a track - let's say to mute it - and the update is only wokring until the next app start. This is, because the udpate is only reflected in the cached list of tracks, but not really persisted to the database.

Here is my code so far (not working)

```
// iterate through tracks
for (Track track : mSongVersion.getTrackList()) {

  if (trackId.equals(track.getId())) {
   // mute specific track
   track.setMuted(muted);
   mSongVersion.update();
  }
}
```

`SongVersion` and `Track` are the entitiy classes genertated by greendao. `SongVersion` has an update()-method, but `Track` has no update()-method. So I was thinking that one has to update a specific track by updating "the whole thing" using SongVersion#update().
But this call only updates the SongVersion, ignoring changes of its tracks...

I also tried some variations of (not) resetting the tracklist to make sure that (no) cached values are interfering, but also to no avail.

**EDIT:**

Here's some code that might help.

SongVersion *(generated by greendao!)*:

```
/** Used for active entity operations. */
private transient SongVersionDao myDao;

/** called by internal mechanisms, do not call yourself. */
public void __setDaoSession(DaoSession daoSession) {
  this.daoSession = daoSession;
  myDao = daoSession != null ? daoSession.getSongVersionDao() : null;
}

public void update() {
  if (myDao == null) {
    throw new DaoException("Entity is detached from DAO context");
  }    
  myDao.update(this);
}
```

Parts of the Database generation java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Schema schema = new Schema(1, "my.app.database");

  Entity songVersion = schema.addEntity("SongVersion");
  Entity track = schema.addEntity("Track");

  // SongVersion fields w/o relations
  songVersion.setHasKeepSections(true);
  songVersion.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
  songVersion.addStringProperty("name").notNull();

  // Track fields w/o relations
  track.setHasKeepSections(true);
  track.implementsInterface("Comparable");
  track.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
  track.addBooleanProperty("muted").notNull();

  // relations
  Property songVersionId =
  track.addLongProperty("songVersionId").notNull().getProperty();
  songVersion.addToMany(track, songVersionId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should use the TrackDAO to update the track after modifying the list instance. Something like this:

```
daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
trackDao = daoSession.getTrackDao();

// iterate through tracks
for (Track track : mSongVersion.getTrackList()) {

  if (trackId.equals(track.getId())) {
   // mute specific track
   track.setMuted(muted);
   trackDao.update(track);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly my problem. I could use the update(Object)-method from the TrackDao (i.e. the inherited update-method from the AbstractDao), but then I still wonder why the generated <code>SongVersion</code> provides a convenient update()-method together with a myDao-field and <code>Track</code> does not.

Comment: I just tested it using the trackDao and it works. But I'd still be happy for an explanation about the missing generated update()-method...

Comment: It's not easy to say without taking a look on the implementation of the SongVersion.update() method. Could you add this part of the code?

Comment: did so, the generated Track-Object does not have a myDao-field and does not have an update()-method. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Seeing your code I have to admit that I don't know why this method it's not present in Track class. My only guess, based on the difference between Track and SongVersion, is that SongVersion may have it because the SongVersion have a relation. Also, keep in mind that updating an Entity never will update in the database the changes made in the related entities, because that might cause a waterfall update of related entities that could be very expensive.

Comment: Hm, too bad. I had the same thought, but SongVersion is in another parent-child relationship itself and I doubt that the generator would realize such a chain of relations and only leaves out the update-method in the "leaf"-entities...Well thanks for your help! I try to reproduce this in a dummy project and leave another comment here in case I find something worthwhile.